# juju: can't add machines again after the destroy-machine command

Tags: 14.04, juju, maas, openstack

I have destroyed machines using

```
$ juju destroy-machine <machine_id>
```

but can't add the machines again. 
Whenever, i do add with this command

```
$ juju add-machine --constraints tags=virtual, controller
```

juju stat shows a new machine in error state.

I have tried

```
$ juju add-machine <machine_name>
```

as well, but same thing is happening.

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comma-delimited list of tags shouldn't have a space between them. Instead, try this:

$ juju add-machine --constraints tags=virtual,controller

Comment: If that still fails, could you clarify which version of juju are you using (`juju version`)? Also, can you check/attach /var/log/juju/machine-#.log

Comment: Ah thanks man, removed the space and it worked..

Comment: I am using juju 1.25.3